# Symfony2 - multiple page login form in modal window

Tags: forms, symfony, authentication

I have this modal window with login form and I am displaying it in multiple page. The problem is that my login form is working only in homepage. It is because I described so in security.yml:

```
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        provider:   main
        form_login:
            login_path:             /
            check_path:             /
            default_target_path:    /authorization
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: homepage
        remember_me:
            secret: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 31536000
```

Do I have to create multiple areas like this one for each page even though it is using exactly same login form in modal window?

For example:

```
contacts_area:
    pattern:    ^/contacts
    anonymous:  ~
    form_login:
        login_path:             /contacts
        check_path:             /contacts
        default_target_path:    /authorization

about_area:
    pattern:    ^/about
    anonymous:  ~
    form_login:
        login_path:             /about
        check_path:             /about
        default_target_path:    /authorization

// and so on
```

Any ideas how overcome this ugly solution? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end after some research I found out that it is impossible to have it done other way. I modified my areas and they are working better than ever:

```
about:
    pattern:    ^/about
    anonymous:  ~
    provider:   main
    context:    primary_auth
    form_login:
        login_path:             /about
        check_path:             /about/login_check
        default_target_path:    /authorization
    remember_me:
        secret: '%secret%'
        lifetime: 31536000
```

I modified check pathes so I could have more forms in same page. Apparently I had submit problems from oter forms in same page as login form. Changing `check_path` fixed the problem.